# How to retrieve files from a drive that has lost its master boot record

Tags: hardware, data-recovery, business-continuity

We have a developer who lost their MBR on their laptop and we would like to recover the sourcecode on his drive does anybody have any suggestions on recovering this data.  We have used FixBoot.exe and FixMBR.exe to replace the damaged boot record and that allows us to do directory searches but nothing returns.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nice blog post and tutorial here:

**[Data recovery - NTFS with broken MBR and MFT](http://www.ctrl-alt-del.cc/2008/03/data-recovery-ntfs-with-broken-mbr-and-mft.html)**

The author mentions the whole procedure and two open source tools:

- [Recover is possible](http://freshmeat.net/projects/recoveryispossible/)
- [Scrounge NTFS](http://memberwebs.com/stef/software/scrounge/)

*I hope you succeed in repairing the partition.

Good luck!*

Comment: I was about to post a similar solution but that blog post/tutorial walks you through the options much better than my answer did.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a bootscan /rebuild and a bootscan /scan

If it is a sata drive hook it up to a PC and try and see if utilities such as Recuva (Freeware) are able to find anything

Answer (score 1):

I'd first try TestDisk to gracefully recover the partition info.  Failing that, I'd then try  PhotoRec to recover the source files.  Both tools can be found at [www.cgsecurity.org](http://www.cgsecurity.org/).

Another good recovery tool is "foremost" which can be found on sourceforge.